# How i call the add to cart button from product review page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, button, mern

How can I called the `handleAddToCart` function from ProductDetails.js page

I want add to cart button work as product page add to cart button like. i try many way like `handleAddToCart={product}` use in productDetails.js but it did not work.

Product.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faShoppingCart } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./Product.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Product = (props) => {
  // console.log(props);
  const { img, name, seller, price, stock, key } = props.product;
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div>
        <img src={img} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4 className="product-name">
          <Link to={"/product/" + key}>{name}</Link>
        </h4>
        <br />
        <p>
          <small>by: {seller}</small>
        </p>
        <p>${price}</p>
        <p>
          <small>Only {stock} left in stock - Order soon</small>
        </p>
        <button
          className="main-button"
          onClick={() => props.handleAddProduct(props.product)}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} /> add to cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

ProductDetails.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import fakeData from "../../fakeData";
import Product from "../Product/Product";

const ProductDetail = () => {
  const { productKey } = useParams();
  const product = fakeData.find((pd) => pd.key === productKey);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your Product Details.</h1>
      <Product handleAddProduct={product} product={product}></Product>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

Shop.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import fakeData from "../../fakeData";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Shop.css";
import Product from "../Product/Product";
import Cart from "../Cart/Cart";
import {
  addToDatabaseCart,
  getDatabaseCart,
} from "../../utilities/databaseManager";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Shop = () => {
  const first10 = fakeData.slice(0, 10);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(first10);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedCart = getDatabaseCart();
    const productKeys = Object.keys(savedCart);
    const previousCart = productKeys.map((existingKey) => {
      const product = fakeData.find((pd) => pd.key === existingKey);
      product.quantity = savedCart[existingKey];
      return product;
    });
    setCart(previousCart);
  }, []);

  const handleAddProduct = (product) => {
    const toBeAddedKey = product.key;
    const sameProduct = cart.find((pd) => pd.key === toBeAddedKey);
    let count = 1;
    let newCart;
    if (sameProduct) {
      count = sameProduct.quantity + 1;
      sameProduct.quantity = count;
      const others = cart.filter((pd) => pd.key !== toBeAddedKey);
      newCart = [...others, sameProduct];
    } else {
      product.quantity = 1;
      newCart = [...cart, product];
    }
    setCart(newCart);
    addToDatabaseCart(product.key, count);
  };

  return (
    <div className="shop-container">
      <div className="product-container">
        {products.map((pd) => (
          <Product
            key={pd.key}
            showAddToCart={true}
            handleAddProduct={handleAddProduct}
            product={pd}
          ></Product>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="cart-container">
        <Cart cart={cart}>
          <Link to="/review">
            <button className="main-button">Review Order</button>
          </Link>
        </Cart>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

I want the add to cart button to work from ProductDetails.js but it can not

I tried many ways to call `handleAddToCart` button but it didn't work

Comment: Where exactly are you using this `ProductDetails` component?

Comment: @RubenSmn actually i want to call the add to cart button for add the product in to the cart item. from productDetails.js file

Comment: It seems to me like you want your `cart` state to be accessible in both the `Shop` `Product` and `ProductDetails` components. I'm not sure how `ProductDetails` is structured in this but you could take a look at [React Context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context), this allows you to have a global state.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to create a custom `React hook` which defines the `handleAddProduct` function and returns it. Then any component that needs that function can use it.

Start by creating the hook, then moving it's dependencies and imports into it:

`useHandleAddProduct.js`:

```
// ...

export default function useHandleAddProduct () {
  
  // ...
  
  const handleAddProduct = (product) =>{
    const toBeAddedKey = product.key;
    const sameProduct = cart.find(pd => pd.key === toBeAddedKey);
    let count = 1;
    let newCart;
    if(sameProduct){
        count = sameProduct.quantity + 1;
        sameProduct.quantity = count;
        const others = cart.filter(pd => pd.key !== toBeAddedKey);
        newCart = [...others, sameProduct];
    } else{
      product.quantity = 1;
      newCart = [...cart, product];
    }
    setCart(newCart);
    addToDatabaseCart(product.key, count);
  }
  
  return handleAddProduct;
}
```

You may need to add some props and move things around in terms of your imports.